# Google Colab and Emacs

Tags: emacs, ipython, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to connect to a collab notebook with ein in emacs. I have tried copying the URL into it but it asks for a password.

Any clue if this is at all possible? Thanks!

https://github.com/millejoh/emacs-ipython-notebook

Comment: If you are using emacs then everything is possible (including nuclear fusion). The question only remains whether someone has already done it. Sadly the answer is no

Comment: I asked this exact question myself too - pity that there is no answer yet

Comment: This would have been trivially possible if Colab did not terminate sessions enabling SSH.

Comment: If through vscode is possible , then it is possible in emacs https://colab.research.google.com/github/JayThibs/jacques-blog/blob/master/_notebooks/2021-09-27-connect-to-colab-from-local-vscode.ipynb#scrollTo=u_nPn26ObgWi